# How to export all filtered records kartik-v/yii2-export in GridView?

Tags: yii2

I am using the extension kartik-v / yii2-export, (Apparently it is the only one there is to export). I have the following inconvenience:

I only exported the first page of the dataprovider.

I would like to filter the data in the grid, and export the filtered data, even if they have several pages. Is this possible?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If i am correct it is a default feature in kartik export :

```
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
$gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    'name',
    'color',
    'publish_date',
    'status',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
];

// Renders a export dropdown menu
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);

// You can choose to render your own GridView separately
echo \kartik\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);
```

**Data provider for the export and grid should be same it will work**

Comment: i think he is asking about exporting specific filtered records via search filter in grid view not sure if it supports by default

Comment: by default it supports sorted and filtered data to be exported as all available options like HTML,CVS,Excel etc , it worked for me by just configuring kartik export extension

Comment: Please, add ('clearBuffers' => true) to the ExportMenu widget setup and try.

Answer (score 1):

In controller create new dataProvider with different name

```
 $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
           'sql' => $data,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
            // 'sort' => [
            //     'attributes' => [
            //           ......
            //     ],
            // ],
        ]);
        $dataExport = new SqlDataProvider([
           'sql' => $data,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => $count_your_data,
            ],
            // 'sort' => [
            //     'attributes' => [
            //           ......
            //     ],
            // ],
        ]);
```

And in view change this

```
// Renders a export dropdown menu
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataExport,
    'columns' => $gridColumns
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I Solved this; by setting the property  'batchSize'  from the Export Widget, the same value the property 'pageSize' from DataProvider. It Works !

Comment: this wont guarantee that those records are similar to those that are filtered , just the number of records would be same